# Why does react-oidc-context give error Error: Only the Authorization Code flow (with PKCE) is supported

Tags: reactjs, oidc-client, react-oidc

I've a react app configured with react-oidc-context and oidc-client. I'm trying to run it with:

```
 response_type: id_token token
```

But it keeps giving me error that `response_type` should only be code. My requirement is that I need to work with implicit flow. How can I do that?

Comment: The service or framework is telling you that only authorization code flow (with PKCE) is supported. So you'll have to change services or frameworks to one that supports the implicit flow that you desire.

Comment: @yusra-masood, from what I am reading, Implicit Flow is now old hat and authorisation code flow (with PKCE) is now recommended ([source](https://blog.postman.com/pkce-oauth-how-to/)).